# INVALID HEAP when using STL make_heap / push_heap / pop_heap

Tags: c++, stl, heap

I have written simple wrapper for std::make_heap / push_heap / pop_heap:

```
template <typename T, typename Cont = std::vector<T>, typename Compare = std::less<typename Cont::value_type> >  
class Heap  
{  
public:  
    inline void init() { std::make_heap(m_data.begin(), m_data.end(), Compare()); }  
    inline void push(const T & elm) { m_data.push_back(elm); std::push_heap(m_data.begin(), m_data.end(), Compare()); }  
    inline const T & top() const { return m_data.front(); }  
    inline void pop() { std::pop_heap(m_data.begin(), m_data.end(), Compare()); m_data.pop_back(); }  

private:  
    Cont m_data;  
};
```

which I use like:

```
class DeliveryComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(Delivery * lhs, Delivery * rhs)
    {
        if(lhs->producer != rhs->producer) return *lhs->producer < *rhs->producer;  
        if(lhs->rate == rhs->rate) return lhs->diff < rhs->diff;  
        return lhs->rate < rhs->rate; 
    }
};

Heap<Delivery*, std::vector<Delivery*>, DeliveryComparator> packages;
```

But sometimes I get *INVALID HEAP* std debug message. 
I use heap just through  proper Heap methods. When message occurs m_data are not empty.

What could be wrong with heap?

*I use MSVS2010

Comment: Why not use `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: Isn't `std::priority_queue` already a wrapper around the heap functions?

Comment: Are there some extra `*` in your comparator, i.e. `*lhs->producer`, should just be `lhs->producer`?

Comment: @KennyTM and Kerrek  : oh I have totally forgotten about priority_queue, thank you. Anyway, Is there something wrong with my Heap?

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda those stars are necessary, producer is pointer-type and I do not want to compare addresses but call operator< at producer instance

Comment: @relaxxx: No idea, we don't have the definition of `Delivery`. The heap code looks OK at a quick glance. The comparator operator should have a lot more `const`s everywhere.

Comment: You say you "sometimes" get a debug message.  Useful exercise: isolate a data set and sequence of operations for which this happens reliably, then post it.

Comment: Also, a minor style note: when you have a sequence of if statements, as in operator(), try to make them as structurally similar as possible.  I'd reverse the order of the second and third comparisons, e.g. "if(lhs->rate != rhs->rate) return lhs->rate < rhs->rate; else return lhs->diff < rhs->diff;".  This also makes it more obvious what your sorting criteria are: first you try to compare producers, and if there's a tie you compare rates, and if there's another tie you compare diffs.

Comment: I have tried to isolate data which caused this error, but I failed... How is even possible to get the heap into bad state, when accessing its data only through mentioned Heap class? There is most likely error somewhere else, but I can still understand how can I invalid the heap without modifying any element. Just pushing and popping on initialized heap... (no range control, but I am sure I never pop from and empty Heap)

Answer (score -1):

After editing the data of the heap (except those pending to add), the heap was destroyed. If you using push_heap() method next, this exception will be thrown out. You should use make_heap() instead of push_heap(). For example (btw, following example is the code snippet from my program):

```
if (highHeap[0] < solvedQuestions){ 
               lowHeap[lenghOfLowHeap++] = highHeap[0]; // *It only add a new item without destroy the heap 
               highHeap[0] = solvedQuestions;
               // Update the Heap
               push_heap(lowHeap, lowHeap + lenghOfLowHeap); 
               //push_heap(highHeap, highHeap + lenghOfHighHeap, greater<int>()); // invalid heap exception. Because the heap was destroyed by "highHeap[0] = solvedQuestions;"
               make_heap(highHeap, highHeap + lenghOfHighHeap, greater<int>());
           }
```

Comment: "A range can be made into a heap by calling function make_heap. Once created, its heap properties can be preserved by using push_heap and pop_heap respectively to add and remove values from it." - from [push_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/)